# pybind11 - ImportError: undefined symbol: _Py_ZeroStruct

Tags: python, c++, ubuntu, pybind11

I'm following the `pybind11` documentation and trying to create Python bindings for a simple function [Creating bindings for a simple function](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/basics.html#creating-bindings-for-a-simple-function), but after compiling my C++ code with the following command:

```sh
g++ -O3 -Wall -shared -std=c++11 -fPIC $(python3 -m pybind11 --includes) example.cc -o example$(python3-config --extension-suffix)
```

when I try to import the library in python using:

```py
import example
```

I get an `ImportError` saying `undefined symbol: _Py_ZeroStruct`

I'm using:

- **Ubuntu** : `Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS`
- **Python** : `Python 3.8.10`
- **Pip** : `Pip 20.0.2`

## What I tried to solve the issue

I looked into many articles related to the same error but couldn't really get an understanding of how I'm going to resolve my issue:

- [Python3.5 incompatibility: undefined symbol](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/issues/1637)
- [ImportError: undefined symbol: _Py_ZeroStruct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66492113/importerror-undefined-symbol-py-zerostruct)
- [undefined symbol using pybind11 cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61475813/undefined-symbol-using-pybind11-cmd)
- [Undefined Symbol error when linking pybind11 with a dynamic library that calls an external function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69525592/undefined-symbol-error-when-linking-pybind11-with-a-dynamic-library-that-calls-a)

**Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated.**

Comment: Are there any other versions of python installed on your computer?

Comment: @MarcGlisse Yes, actually there are a lot of versions of Python installed and the default Python version is `Python 3.7.13`. However, `Python 3.8.10` is the Python version that I'm using in my virtualenv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after trying a lot of methods I finally decided to add `pybind11` as a submodule in my project and use `Python3.9` and it seemed to work this time.

Anyone struggling with the same problem can try my method, it may work and **don't expect help from this cruel community**.